# Do I need to modify my HTML document every time I want to add an article to my site?

Tags: html, css, web

I want to create a really simple blog and so far I learned HTML and CSS.

So if I want to add a new node or article, do I need to modify my HTML document and then upload it again or is there any other way?

Comment: hey Alexander, Using only CSS and HTML you can build only Static Website.For Dynamic Website  you need to use PHP or other server side scripting language.

Comment: `ajax` is your choice

Comment: @DhruvRaval Planning to learn JS as well or should I learn JS at first and only then build a Website?

Comment: if you use HTML and CSS you need to write them each time. If you use js you can make it automatic. HTML and CSS help you make only static websites.

Comment: Learning first JS is better @Alexander.

Comment: as per my suggestion. you need to learn JS and PHP both for dynamic website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If you're only using simple HTML**
Then the css should be made in a way that would make it reusable, so that when you just add another article shouldn't affect anyhing else. The HTML however must be changed, as you'll need to add your content somehow
The thing is, no one uses plain HTML anymore. If you want everything to happen dynamically then you should use DOM manipulation frameworks. The most basic one of which is *JQuery*, while the most powerful ones as of now are *React, Angular, and Vue*

Answer (score 0):

Well, of course you have to modify something and upload it again, but not necessarily the HTML code.
You could youse AJAX (Asynchronous JavaScript and XML) - which, by the way, you can also use with JSON instead of XML - then create a standard article model, get the latest article from your file with

```
fetch("your-file.xml-or-json-or-whatever").then(
    function(response) { /* Do something with the response, see the link below for an example */ }
);
```

and finally turn it into a DOM element with JS.
This method is pretty inefficient, though, if you don't have a way to cut the output from your list of articles. In fact, if, say, you have one thousand articles, it's inconvenient (inconvenient to say the least) to serve them all and the just use the first ten. If you have a static server, you might want to split the content into multiple files. If, instead, you have access to PHP (or other HTML preprocessors), then you should consider cutting it dynamically. Below are some links to help you.

[AJAX tutorial on W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_ajax_intro.asp)
[Fetch documentation on Mozilla Developer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)

You could also think of using frameworks like Angular (or AngularJS) to make your website even more dynamic. However, those are better for web apps than websites, as I've heard that it's a bit harder for Google to register an Angular app.